# Why does destroy method 'close' fail for JPAPagingItemReader configured with Java config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

We are trying to convert our Spring-Batch jobs from XML configuration to Java configuration. We are using Spring 4.0.1.RELEASE and Spring Batch 2.2.1.RELEASE.

After converting one job, the following warning started to appear in the log file:

> 15-Apr-2014 09:59:26.335 [Thread-2] WARN  o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invocation of destroy method 'close' failed on bean with name 'fileReader': org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Error while closing item reader

The full stacktrace is:

```
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Error while closing item reader
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.close(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:131) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.invokeCustomDestroyMethod(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:349) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:272) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:540) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:516) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:824) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:485) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:921) [spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895) [spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:809) [spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.close(EntityManagerImpl.java:132) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.5.Final.jar:4.2.5.Final]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_25]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:334) ~[spring-orm-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy67.close(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader.doClose(JpaPagingItemReader.java:236) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.close(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:128) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

This error only appears when using the Java configuration for the job but not the XML configuration. The step configured using XML looks like this:

```xml
<batch:step id="createFile" next="insertFile">
    <batch:tasklet>
        <batch:chunk reader="fileReader" writer="fileWriter"
            commit-interval="#{jobProperties[commit_interval]}" />
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>

<bean id="fileReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="queryString"
        value="select mt from MyTable mt where status in ('1','2','3')" />
    <property name="pageSize" value="1000" />
</bean>
```

The Java configuration is:

```
@Bean
public Job fileProcessJob(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilders,
        Step loadConfig,
        Step createFile,
        Step insertFile
        ) {
    return jobBuilders.get(moduleName)
            .start(loadConfig)
            .next(createFile)
            .next(insertFile)
            .build()
            .build();
}

@Bean
public ItemReader<MyTable> cetFileReader(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaPagingItemReader<MyTable> itemReader = new JpaPagingItemReader<MyTable>();
    itemReader.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    itemReader.setQueryString("select mt from MyTable mt where status in ('1','2','3')");
    itemReader.setPageSize(1000);
    return itemReader;
}
```

Why does this warning appear in the logs when using Java configuration but not XML configuration?

Comment: what is the jdk version ? You should use Java 1.7

Comment: Is this the *only* difference? The error message is quite clear: The `close` method has already been called before the `destroy` tries to close it again. I suspect some other difference in the code as well, possibly relating to transaction management.

Comment: @chrylis Yes it is the only difference. I could not figure out why the reader was being closed twice. The step is normally responsible for closing the reader at the appropriate time. However, for some reason, the reader was trying to be closed a second time when the application context was being destroyed. My answer explains why this was happening.

Comment: Please move to Java 1.7 Then it would work..

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**TLDR;**

Spring tries to automatically infer a `destroyMethod` when using Java configuration (but it does not do so when using XML configuration). To disable this automatic inference, use:

`@Bean(destroyMethod="")`

---

The answer is in the JavaDoc of the `@Bean` annotation; specifically on the `org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean.destroyMethod()` method (emphasis mine):

> The optional name of a method to call on the bean instance upon closing the application context, for example a close() method on a JDBC DataSource implementation, or a Hibernate SessionFactory object. The method must have no arguments but may throw any exception.
>
> **As a convenience to the user, the container will attempt to infer a destroy method against an object returned from the @Bean method.** For example, given a @Bean method returning an Apache Commons DBCP BasicDataSource, the container will notice the close() method available on that object and automatically register it as the destroyMethod. This 'destroy method inference' is currently limited to detecting only public, no-arg methods named 'close'. The method may be declared at any level of the inheritance hierarchy and will be detected regardless of the return type of the @Bean method (i.e., detection occurs reflectively against the bean instance itself at creation time).
>
> **To disable destroy method inference for a particular @Bean, specify an empty string as the value, e.g. @Bean(destroyMethod="").** Note that the org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean and the java.io.Closeable/java.lang.AutoCloseable interfaces will nevertheless get detected and the corresponding destroy/close method invoked.
>
> Note: Only invoked on beans whose lifecycle is under the full control of the factory, which is always the case for singletons but not guaranteed for any other scope.

After changing the Java configuration to:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod="")
public ItemReader<MyTable> cetFileReader(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaPagingItemReader<MyTable> itemReader = new JpaPagingItemReader<MyTable>();
    itemReader.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    itemReader.setQueryString("select mt from MyTable mt where status in ('1','2','3')");
    itemReader.setPageSize(1000);
    return itemReader;
}
```

The warning did not show up anymore. I was able to confirm this by placing a breakpoint on the `org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy()` method and launching XML configured job and the Java configured job.

For the XML configuration:

- DisposableBeanAdapter.invokeDisposableBean = false
- DisposableBeanAdapter.destroyMethod = null
- DisposableBeanAdapter.destroyMethodName = null

For the Java configuration (without `destroyMethod=""` set):

- DisposableBeanAdapter.invokeDisposableBean = false
- DisposableBeanAdapter.destroyMethod = *public void org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.close() throws org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException*
- DisposableBeanAdapter.destroyMethodName = close

For the Java configuration (with `destroyMethod=""` set):

- DisposableBeanAdapter.invokeDisposableBean = false
- DisposableBeanAdapter.destroyMethod = null
- DisposableBeanAdapter.destroyMethodName = null

Based on these observations, I come to the conclusion that the container does not try to infer a destroy method when configured via XML; but it does when configured via Java. Which is why the warning shows up for the Java configuration and not the XML configuration.

Additionally, the method the container infers is the destroyMethod seems to come from `org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamSupport.close()`. So this could potentially happen to any bean that implements the `ItemStreamSupport` interface that is configured via the `@Bean` annotation.

---

A note has been added to the [Spring Framework Reference material for @Bean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-lifecycle-callbacks) describing this behavior:

> By default, beans defined using Java config that have a public close or shutdown method are automatically enlisted with a destruction callback. If you have a public close or shutdown method and you do not wish for it to be called when the container shuts down, simply add @Bean(destroyMethod="") to your bean definition to disable the default (inferred) mode.