# Spring Batch Processor not running ItemProcessorListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, listeners

So I have a problem in Spring Batch `3.0.7.RELEASE` and Spring `4.3.2.RELEASE` where the Listeners are not running in my `ItemProcessor` class.  Regular injection at the `@StepScope` level is working for `@Value("#{jobExecutionContext['" + Constants.SECURITY_TOKEN + "']}")` as seen below. But it isn't working for `beforeProcess` or `beforeStep`, I have tried both the annotation version and interface version.  I'm almost 100% sure this was working at some point, but can't figure out why it's stopped.

Any ideas? Does it look like I have configured it wrong?

AppBatchConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "our.org.base")
public class AppBatchConfiguration {

    private final static SimpleLogger LOGGER = SimpleLogger.getInstance(AppBatchConfiguration.class);

    private final static String OUTPUT_XML_FILE_PATH_PLACEHOLDER = null;
    private final static String INPUT_XML_FILE_PATH_PLACEHOLDER = null;

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean(name = "cimAppXmlReader")
    @StepScope
    public <T> ItemStreamReader<T> appXmlReader(@Value("#{jobParameters[inputXmlFilePath]}")
    String inputXmlFilePath) {
        LOGGER.info("Job Parameter => App XML File Path :" + inputXmlFilePath);
        StaxEventItemReader<T> reader = new StaxEventItemReader<T>();
        reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(inputXmlFilePath));
        reader.setUnmarshaller(mecaUnMarshaller());
        reader.setFragmentRootElementNames(getAppRootElementNames());
        reader.setSaveState(false);

        // Make the StaxEventItemReader thread-safe
        SynchronizedItemStreamReader<T> synchronizedItemStreamReader = new SynchronizedItemStreamReader<T>();
        synchronizedItemStreamReader.setDelegate(reader);

        return synchronizedItemStreamReader;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemStreamReader<JAXBElement<AppIBTransactionHeaderType>> appXmlTransactionHeaderReader(@Value("#{jobParameters[inputXmlFilePath]}")
    String inputXmlFilePath) {
        LOGGER.info("Job Parameter => App XML File Path for Transaction Header :" + inputXmlFilePath);
        StaxEventItemReader<JAXBElement<AppIBTransactionHeaderType>> reader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(inputXmlFilePath));
        reader.setUnmarshaller(mecaUnMarshaller());

        String[] fragmentRootElementNames = new String[] {"AppIBTransactionHeader"};
        reader.setFragmentRootElementNames(fragmentRootElementNames);
        reader.setSaveState(false);

        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public Unmarshaller mecaUnMarshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setPackagesToScan(ObjectFactory.class.getPackage().getName());
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public Marshaller uberMarshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(ServiceRequestType.class);
        marshaller.setSupportJaxbElementClass(true);
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod="") // To stop multiple close calls, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23089536
    @StepScope
    public ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream<JAXBElement<ServiceRequestType>> writer(@Value("#{jobParameters[outputXmlFilePath]}")
    String outputXmlFilePath) {
        SyncStaxEventItemWriter<JAXBElement<ServiceRequestType>> writer = new SyncStaxEventItemWriter<JAXBElement<ServiceRequestType>>();

        writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(outputXmlFilePath));
        writer.setMarshaller(uberMarshaller());
        writer.setSaveState(false);
        HashMap<String, String> rootElementAttribs = new HashMap<String, String>();
        rootElementAttribs.put("xmlns:ns1", "http://some.org/corporate/message/2010/1");
        writer.setRootElementAttributes(rootElementAttribs);
        writer.setRootTagName("ns1:SetOfServiceRequests");

        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public <T> ItemProcessor<T, JAXBElement<ServiceRequestType>> appNotificationProcessor() {
        return new AppBatchNotificationItemProcessor<T>();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<JAXBElement<AppIBTransactionHeaderType>, Boolean> appBatchCreationProcessor() {
        return new AppBatchCreationItemProcessor();
    }


    public String[] getAppRootElementNames() {        
        //get list of App Transaction Element Names        
        return AppProcessorEnum.getValues();         
    }

    @Bean
    public Step AppStep() {
        // INPUT_XML_FILE_PATH_PLACEHOLDER and OUTPUT_XML_FILE_PATH_PLACEHOLDER will be overridden 
        // by injected jobParameters using late binding (StepScope)
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("AppStep")
                .<Object, JAXBElement<ServiceRequestType>> chunk(10)
                .reader(appXmlReader(INPUT_XML_FILE_PATH_PLACEHOLDER))
                .processor(appNotificationProcessor())
                .writer(writer(OUTPUT_XML_FILE_PATH_PLACEHOLDER))
                .taskExecutor(concurrentTaskExecutor())
                .throttleLimit(1)
                .build();

    }

    @Bean
    public Step BatchCreationStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("BatchCreationStep")
                .<JAXBElement<AppIBTransactionHeaderType>, Boolean>chunk(1)
                .reader(appXmlTransactionHeaderReader(INPUT_XML_FILE_PATH_PLACEHOLDER))
                .processor(appBatchCreationProcessor())
                .taskExecutor(concurrentTaskExecutor())
                .throttleLimit(1)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job AppJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("AppJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(AppJobCompletionNotificationListener())
                .flow(AppStep())
                .next(BatchCreationStep())
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobCompletionNotificationListener AppJobCompletionNotificationListener() {
        return new JobCompletionNotificationListener();
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor concurrentTaskExecutor() {
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(1);
        return taskExecutor;
    }
}
```

AppBatchNotificationItemProcessor.java

```
@StepScope
public class AppBatchNotificationItemProcessor<E> extends AppAbstractItemProcessor<E, JAXBElement<ServiceRequestType>> implements ItemProcessor<E, JAXBElement<ServiceRequestType>>, StepExecutionListener {

    // This is populated correctly
    @Value("#{jobExecutionContext['" + Constants.SECURITY_TOKEN + "']}")
    private SecurityToken securityToken;

    @Autowired
    private AppProcessorService processor;

    @Override
    public JAXBElement<ServiceRequestType> process(E item) throws BPException {
        // Do Stuff
        return srRequest;
    }

    @BeforeProcess
    public void beforeProcess(E item) {
        System.out.println("Doesn't execute");
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        // Doesn't execute
        System.out.println("Doesn't execute");
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        // Doesn't execute
        System.out.println("Doesn't execute");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that you are returning interfaces instead of implementations in your `@Bean` methods.  IMHO, you should return the most specific type possible when using java configuration in Spring.  Here's why:

When configuring via XML, you provide the class in the XML configuration.  This exposes the implementation to Spring so that any interfaces the class implements can be discovered and handled appropriately.  When using java configuration, the return type of the `@Bean` method serves as the replacement for that information.  And there is the issue.  If your return type is an interface, Spring only knows about that specific interface and not all the interfaces an implementation may implement.  By returning the concrete type where you can, you give Spring insight into what you're actually returning so it can better handle the various registration and wiring use cases for you.

For your specific example, since you're returning an `ItemProcessor` and it's step scoped (therefore proxied), all Spring knows about are the methods/behaviors expected with the `ItemProcessor` interface.  If you return the implementation (`AppBatchNotificationItemProcessor`), other behaviors can be autoconfigured.

Comment: Thanks Michael,  that did the job.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, you have to register a reader, writer, processor directly as listener on the step, if you use StepScope.

StepScope prevents the framework from being able to figure out what kind of interfaces, resp. @annotations (e.g.@BeforeProcess) the proxy actually implements/defines and therefore it is not able to register it as a listener.

So, I assume if add

```
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("AppStep")
            .<Object, JAXBElement<ServiceRequestType>> chunk(10)
            .reader(appXmlReader(INPUT_XML_FILE_PATH_PLACEHOLDER))
            .processor(appNotificationProcessor())
            .writer(writer(OUTPUT_XML_FILE_PATH_PLACEHOLDER))

        .listener(appNotificationProcessor())

            .taskExecutor(concurrentTaskExecutor())
            .throttleLimit(1)
            .build();
```

it will work.