# Spring Batch Prototype Scope for Item Processor

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

So I have a problem in Spring Batch `3.0.7.RELEASE` and Spring `4.3.2.RELEASE` where we want to use the `prototype` scope for the ItemProcessor when using concurrency.

See `appBatchCreationProcessor()` and `BatchCreationStep()`, I've tried to make the scope of `appBatchCreationProcessor` `prototype`, but it doesn't seem to have any effect, the same item processor is used across all 10 threads.

Is there a way around this? Or is this by design?

AppBatchConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "our.org.base")
public class AppBatchConfiguration {

    private final static SimpleLogger LOGGER = SimpleLogger.getInstance(AppBatchConfiguration.class);

    private final static String OUTPUT_XML_FILE_PATH_PLACEHOLDER = null;
    private final static String INPUT_XML_FILE_PATH_PLACEHOLDER = null;

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean(name = "cimAppXmlReader")
    @StepScope
    public <T> ItemStreamReader<T> appXmlReader(@Value("#{jobParameters[inputXmlFilePath]}")
    String inputXmlFilePath) {
        LOGGER.info("Job Parameter => App XML File Path :" + inputXmlFilePath);
        StaxEventItemReader<T> reader = new StaxEventItemReader<T>();
        reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(inputXmlFilePath));
        reader.setUnmarshaller(mecaUnMarshaller());
        reader.setFragmentRootElementNames(getAppRootElementNames());
        reader.setSaveState(false);

        // Make the StaxEventItemReader thread-safe
        SynchronizedItemStreamReader<T> synchronizedItemStreamReader = new SynchronizedItemStreamReader<T>();
        synchronizedItemStreamReader.setDelegate(reader);

        return synchronizedItemStreamReader;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemStreamReader<JAXBElement<AppIBTransactionHeaderType>> appXmlTransactionHeaderReader(@Value("#{jobParameters[inputXmlFilePath]}")
    String inputXmlFilePath) {
        LOGGER.info("Job Parameter => App XML File Path for Transaction Header :" + inputXmlFilePath);
        StaxEventItemReader<JAXBElement<AppIBTransactionHeaderType>> reader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(inputXmlFilePath));
        reader.setUnmarshaller(mecaUnMarshaller());

        String[] fragmentRootElementNames = new String[] {"AppIBTransactionHeader"};
        reader.setFragmentRootElementNames(fragmentRootElementNames);
        reader.setSaveState(false);

        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public Unmarshaller mecaUnMarshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setPackagesToScan(ObjectFactory.class.getPackage().getName());
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public Marshaller uberMarshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(ServiceRequestType.class);
        marshaller.setSupportJaxbElementClass(true);
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod="") // To stop multiple close calls, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23089536
    @StepScope
    public ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream<JAXBElement<ServiceRequestType>> writer(@Value("#{jobParameters[outputXmlFilePath]}")
    String outputXmlFilePath) {
        SyncStaxEventItemWriter<JAXBElement<ServiceRequestType>> writer = new SyncStaxEventItemWriter<JAXBElement<ServiceRequestType>>();

        writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(outputXmlFilePath));
        writer.setMarshaller(uberMarshaller());
        writer.setSaveState(false);
        HashMap<String, String> rootElementAttribs = new HashMap<String, String>();
        rootElementAttribs.put("xmlns:ns1", "http://some.org/corporate/message/2010/1");
        writer.setRootElementAttributes(rootElementAttribs);
        writer.setRootTagName("ns1:SetOfServiceRequests");

        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public <T> ItemProcessor<T, JAXBElement<ServiceRequestType>> appNotificationProcessor() {
        return new AppBatchNotificationItemProcessor<T>();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(scopeName=ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public ItemProcessor<JAXBElement<AppIBTransactionHeaderType>, Boolean> appBatchCreationProcessor() {
        return new AppBatchCreationItemProcessor();
    }


    public String[] getAppRootElementNames() {        
        //get list of App Transaction Element Names        
        return AppProcessorEnum.getValues();         
    }

    @Bean
    public Step AppStep() {
        // INPUT_XML_FILE_PATH_PLACEHOLDER and OUTPUT_XML_FILE_PATH_PLACEHOLDER will be overridden 
        // by injected jobParameters using late binding (StepScope)
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("AppStep")
                .<Object, JAXBElement<ServiceRequestType>> chunk(10)
                .reader(appXmlReader(INPUT_XML_FILE_PATH_PLACEHOLDER))
                .processor(appNotificationProcessor())
                .writer(writer(OUTPUT_XML_FILE_PATH_PLACEHOLDER))
                .taskExecutor(concurrentTaskExecutor())
                .throttleLimit(1)
                .build();

    }

    @Bean
    public Step BatchCreationStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("BatchCreationStep")
                .<JAXBElement<AppIBTransactionHeaderType>, Boolean>chunk(1)
                .reader(appXmlTransactionHeaderReader(INPUT_XML_FILE_PATH_PLACEHOLDER))
                .processor(appBatchCreationProcessor())
                .taskExecutor(concurrentTaskExecutor())
                .throttleLimit(10)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job AppJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("AppJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(AppJobCompletionNotificationListener())
                .flow(AppStep())
                .next(BatchCreationStep())
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobCompletionNotificationListener AppJobCompletionNotificationListener() {
        return new JobCompletionNotificationListener();
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor concurrentTaskExecutor() {
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(10);
        return taskExecutor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is by design.

Think of a job and its steps with its reader, processor, and writer as a static structure that is created before the job gets executed. This means, that your appropriate createReader, createProcessor methods had been called and the bean instances had been created before the job is executed.

SCOPE_PROTOTYPE is evaluated during this phase and since your createProcessor method is called only once during this phase, there will be only one instance of it.

After the job is started, this structure stays "stable".

Now, Spring Batch tweaks that a little bit by providing a "stepscope" which defers bean creation to the start of the step. However, this will not help if you run your step with multiple threads. There is still only one instance of, let's say the processor in your example, and this instance is used for all threads.

What you would need is something like a "ThreadScope" but there isn't such a concept inside spring or spring-batch. You would need to implement your processor accordingly, for instance by using ThreadLocal members.

For instance, you could wrap your Processor in something like this:

```
public class ThreadLocalItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor {

    private ThreadLocal<ItemProcessor> threadProcessor = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> new MyProcessor());

    @Override
    public Object process(Object item) throws Exception {
        return threadProcessor.get().process(item);
    }
}
```

Edit: **Example with prototype method**

If your Processor is instantiated as a SpringBean, it can also use Autowired for injection. Therefore, you could inject a prototype-factory (of course, the prototype-factory has to be instantiated as springbean) as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class PrototypeFactory {
    @Bean
    @Scope(Prototype)
    public YourInterfaceOrClass createInstance() {
         return new YourInterfaceOrClass();
    }
}

public class ThreadLocalItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor {

    @Autowired
    private PrototypeFactory prototypeFactory;

    private ThreadLocal<ItemProcessor> threadProcessor = ThreadLocal.withInitial(this::processorCreator);

    @Override
    public Object process(Object item) throws Exception {
        return threadProcessor.get().process(item);
    }

    //ItemProcessor directly implemented as lambda
    // this will only be called once per working thread
    private Object process(Object input) {

       // will produce a valid SpringBean instance
       YourInterfaceOrClass inst = prototypeFactory.createInstance();

       ... process the input           
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose the thread local processor would not be able to inject anything because spring isn't controlling the lifecycle anymore?  I think our best bet is to have a `@Lookup` method inside the ItemProcessor for the things that need to have a prototype scope.

Comment: I have added an example to my answer. This should produce a valid springBean instance per thread.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the same of `appBatchCreationProcessor()` is used in all thread is because it is injected into a singleton BatchCreationStep(). Furthermore, the `BatchCreationStep()` is also injected into a singleton `AppJob()`

According to [this documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-sing-prot-interaction):

> When you use singleton-scoped beans with dependencies on prototype
>   beans, be aware that dependencies are resolved at instantiation time.
>   Thus if you dependency-inject a prototype-scoped bean into a
>   singleton-scoped bean, a new prototype bean is instantiated and then
>   dependency-injected into the singleton bean. The prototype instance is
>   the sole instance that is ever supplied to the singleton-scoped bean.

However if you do really need to create a new `appBatchCreationProcessor()`, you can use [method injection](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-method-injection)

Comment: Even using method injection, it's still only going to inject one `appBatchCreationProcessor()` isn't it? Because it will only get called once?  I'm guessing I'd have to write a custom task executor or something to redo the injection or something weird.

It's looking like that we can solve our problems using `@Lookup` inside the ItemProcessor for the parts that need to be thread safe.

Comment: @JoelPearson No, please read the method injection link above carefully. Method injection works by resolving the dependency at runtime, not at instantiation time.

Comment: yes, I realise that bit, but won't the spring batch framework only run/evaluate `appBatchCreationProcessor()` when it creates the step? And then share that instance with all the threads? Or do you think it will call appBatchCreationProcessor() for each thread?

Comment: You need to modify the `Step` such that it can be wired up with `ApplicationContext`. You can do that by overwriting the `Step` and `StepBuilderFactory`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, I'm relatively new to Spring, mostly JEE before that. Do you mean extend the Step and StepBuilderFactory and implement `ApplicationContextAware`? I tried annotating `appBatchCreationProcessor()` with `@Lookup` but that gave me `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: $$beanFactory`, with the main exception `Failed to load ApplicationContext`.  Which is I guess what you're referring to?

Comment: If you don't have control to modify the original `Step` and `StepBuilderFactory`, then yes you need to extend both of them to implement `ApplicationContextAware`.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, this will not help. The step with its reader, processor and writer instances is build before it is executed and the concurrency configs you are using (parallel processing of chunks in your case) has no influence during the creation of the step. If you really need an instance per thread, you have to implement a wrapper processor, something like i suggested in my answer. Of course, you you could write your own Steps and Factories and try to come up with another solution, but especially being new to Spring/SpringBatch I would definitely not recommend it.